# Degenerations of smooth projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

**Vague question.** Is there anything special about degenerations of smooth projective varieties (separating them from arbitrary projective schemes)?

**Precise setup.** Let $f:X\to Y$ be a projective flat morphism of algebraic schemes (say, over $\mathbb{C}$), 
where $Y$ is an irreducible variety. Suppose that the generic fiber of $f$ is smooth and connected. Consider special fibers $X_y=f^{-1}(y)$, $y\in Y$. Of course, $X_y$ may be singular, reducible, and/or non-reduced. Zariski's main theorem implies $X_y$ is connected. 
Can we say anything else?

**Specific Questions.** Can $X_y$ have embedded components? Can $X_y$ have non-constant regular functions? (Since $X_y$ is connected, such a regular function would
have to be nilpotent.)

**Reformulation.** Consider a Hilbert scheme of closed subschemes in ${\mathbb P}^N$
(with fixed Hilbert polynomial). There is an open subset in it corresponding to smooth 
connected projective varieties. The question concerns the closure of this set.

*Remark.* I ran across this in a concrete situation, where the goal is to understand $Rf_*O_X$. But it seems that the question is quite natural, so perhaps the corresponding statements or counterexamples are well known... Any comments would be helpful!

Comment: It seems the coherent cohom is better behaved than etale cohom for degenerations, but it wouldn't hurt to consider $Rf_*Q_l$ (or $Rf_*Z$) too. When $f$ is a log smooth morphism between log smooth varieties (e.g. semi-stable degen), the log de Rham complex is well-behaved (e.g. one still has Poincare lemma and de Rham isom; see relevant works of F. Kato and Nakayama etc.), and the results are better stated on the space $X^{log}$ assoc. to $X.$ Hopefully one gets some info about $Rf_*O_X$ when running the Hodge-de Rham spectral seq. 

Comment: Note that Zariski's main theorem applies only when the generic fiber is geometrically connected (otherwise consider an étale cover).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1: Sure, you can have embedded components. Project a curve in $P^3$ into a plane. Where the image crosses itself, you get embedded points.

You can improve connected to "set-theoretically equidimensional, and  connected in codimension 1".

I think the real moral should be that you shouldn't keep track just of the scheme structure when you're done degenerating a smooth variety, but of e.g. the induced log structure, and consider a moduli space of varieties + that extra structure. I should probably ask a question about that!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Of course, having embedded points also means there will be non-trivial regular functions. (I wonder if I should decouple the two questions: suppose there are no embedded components: can there still be non-trivial functions?)

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer: if $X$ is normal and $Y$ is smooth of dimension $1$, then $X_y$ only have constant regular functions ($X\to Y$ is *cohomologically flat* in relative dimension $0$). This is proved in Raynaud: [Spécialisation du foncteur de Picard](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_1970__38_/PMIHES_1970__38__27_0/PMIHES_1970__38__27_0.pdf), Prop. 6.4.2 (use the characteristic 0 hypothesis here, otherwise it is false even when $X$ is also smooth.) It is also proved in the begining of ''Surfaces fibrées en courbes de genre deux'', Lecture Notes in Math. 1137 (1985) by Gang Xiao.

Add: and of course in this situation $X_y$ has no embedded point as $X$ is (S$_2$).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very interesting. From a quick glance at Raynaud's text, it seems that Chapter 6 might have some other relevant statements --- I'll see how much I can get form it...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are asking about *smoothability* of singularities. Some singularities are smoothable some are not.

I don't think there is a general criterion that tells you how to decide whether a specific singularity is smoothable or not and it may not be that a singularity that seems bad is necessarily not smoothable while one that looks OK is.

Hypersurface singularities are smoothable. I bet you can see why.

The simplest example I know of an innocent looking non-smoothable singularity is a cone over an abelian variety of dimension at least $2$. The fact that this is not smoothable follows from that it is a Du Bois singularity and hence by a result of [Schwede](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract;jsessionid=DE028DE09160EB0247C26B83F3DEC272.tomcat1?fromPage=online&aid=1207968) if it were smoothable, the total space would have rational singularities, which is CM, and then all fibers are CM, but this singularity is not. The same argument shows that any projective variety (or variety with isolated singularities) with DB but not CM singularities give examples of what cannot be the limit of smooth projective varieties.

Another set of examples is provided by quotient singularities. They are rigid and hence non-smoothable in dimension at least $3$, but there are two-dimensional quotient singularities that are smoothable, for instance $\big(\mathbb A^2/(x,y)\sim (-x,-y)\big)\simeq (x^2=yz)\subset \mathbb A^3$ is a hypersurface singularity.

If you put more conditions on $f$ that obviously limits further the possible singularities you can get.

**EDIT** incorporated Karl's comment into the example given.

Comment: Is it even known if dimension 1 singularities are smoothable?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am somewhat confused about the last paragraph. Isn't the constant term of the Hilbert polynomial the 
Euler characteristic of the structure sheaf rather than dimension of the space of global sections? After all, the example from Allen Knutson's answer is a curve degenerating into a curve with an embedded point; it does have non-trivial regular functions (supported at the embedded point). What I am wondering about now is whether it is possible to have non-trivial regular functions without embedded components.

Comment: You are totally right. That was silly. Sorry. First I actually gave an example and then I convinced myself that it was wrong. Yes, of course, Allen's example gives you that. On the other hand I am not sure that you can have one that's supported on the entire fiber.

Comment: @Allen: I think you are right. It seems that in some sense this question is harder for smaller dimension or at least that in higher dimension one can ask for the fibers to be normal or having higher depth.

Comment: To Allen: There are examples of 1-dimensional singularities which are not smoothable. This was shown by David Mumford in "Pathologies IV".

Comment: Sandor, the question of smoothability looks like local, while the original question is global. Do you mean that local-to-global passage is trivial in this case?

Comment: Just clarifying my previous comment.  I don't think you need the LC => Du Bois statement to give an easy proof using that machinary.  Suppose it was smoothable, you know the central fiber is either LC or Du Bois (both are easy to check for this singularity).  Then outside the special fiber, it is smooth and so the total space has rational / klt singularities, and is in particular CM (Cohen-Macaulay).  So the special fiber is also CM.  But the cone over an Abelian variety isn't CM.

Comment: Karl, that was pretty much my thinking, but you are right I don't need the LC $\Rightarrow$ DB statement for this particular singularity. So, saying that the total space is rational is fine, but for klt you would need that the total space is $\mathbb Q$-Gorenstein. I don't think you can get that from the assumptions. But you don't need it as the DB/rtl angle works fine. On the other hand, the fact that if the special fiber is DB then the total space is rtl is non-trivial (even if easy) as you knnow very well.

Comment: Sasha, you are right, this is not the same, but for isolated singularities it is. The main related question is, if you have a local scheme with given type of singularities, is it possible to find a compactification with the same type. As far as I know very little is known about this. At the same time, if you have a non-smoothable singularity, it will be non-smoothable even on a projective variety so it does give an example of what does not happen. Of course, there is the possibility that having compact fibers give more restriction. This is an interesting question.