# Direct image of structure sheaf under base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Dear all,

Here is a problem I came across recently. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper morphism of Noetherian schemes and assume that $f_*\mathcal{O}_X\cong \mathcal{O}_Y$. Now let $S$ be a subscheme of $Y$, denote $T:=S\times_YX$ and let $f':T\to S$ be the projection.

Is it then true that $f'_*\mathcal{O}_T\cong \mathcal{O}_S$? If not, can you give an example where this does not work? In that case, are there may be general extra conditions on $X,Y$ and $f$ such that it does work?

Comment: It's not true in general. Basically, you ask whether $f$ is cohomologically flat (in degree zero), see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61289/cohomological-flatness-in-degree-0

For a specific counterexample and some discussion, see 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56019/degenerations-of-smooth-projective-varieties

Namely (quoting from Allen Knutson's answer to last question): let $f$ be a flat family of curves degenerating into a curve with an embedded point.

Comment: An example is an elliptic fibration with wild fibres. See paper of Bombieri and Mumford on classification of surfaces in positive characteristic.

Comment: @Ekedahl. Thank you, that is a nice example! Do you also happen to know an example in characteristic 0?

Comment: @Bart: Not for elliptic fibrations, wild fibres only exist in positive characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

The property you want is called cohomological flatness. See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61289/cohomological-flatness-in-degree-0). You can check out Hartshorne's chapter on semi-continuity and base change, but I would recommend Mumford's quick treatment in his book 'Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface' (this is just a [great book](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/2404.html) in general). There are also notes by Nitin Nitsure in [FGA Explained](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fundamental-Algebraic-Geometry-Grothendiecks-Mathematical/dp/0821842455) in his chapter on the Hilbert scheme. Of course, you can also always look at EGA III.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example where this doesn't work:

Let $Y$ be normal, $S\subset Y$ be non-normal and $f:X\to Y$ an embedded resolution of $S$. (To make it concrete, you may choose $Y=\mathbb P^2$, $S=Z(x^2-y^2)$ (or a nodal cubic) and $f:X\to Y$ the blow up of the singular point of $S$).

Then $T$ is the resolution of $S$ and since it is not-normal, $f'_*\mathscr O_T\not\simeq \mathscr O_S$, but $Y$ is normal, so $f_*\mathscr O_X\simeq \mathscr O_Y$.